# Xamarin IOS Encoding/Decoding Images from and to Base64

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am working on an application for IOS in Xamarin. I have a menu in which I request something called "Doublechecks". These doublechecks have a field with the name "Medication". In a previous working copy of the app, I simply used a string to fill this field, but now we had the idea to, instead of filling this medication field with a string, to fill it with an image. One of the tips I got was to convert a taken or chosen image to base64.

In the menu where I make a new doublecheck I have a button that pops up an actionsheet, where you can choose weather you want to pick an image from your PhotoLibrary, or take a new picture with your camera. When you've taken or chosen a picture, I use the following method to encode it to Base64:

```
var imageToSend = originalImage.AsJPEG (0.23f).GetBase64EncodedString (NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
```

Where the originalImage is the image I took/chose. Now, when requesting all doublechecks, I use the following to decode it:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String (imageToDisplay);
string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (encodedDataAsBytes);
NSData data = NSData.FromString (decoded, NSStringEncoding.ASCIIStringEncoding);
return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
```

The method works up until the return. Somehow, the UIImage is not being constructed, and has its value null, even though the 'data' contains the decoded string.

I have searched several threads and fora, but without much avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you converting the base64 **decoded** data into a `string` ?

Since you already have the byte array you should be able to simply do:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String (imageToDisplay);
NSData data = NSData.FromArray (encodedDataAsBytes);
return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
```

Comment: This was because I already tried to initialise a new NSData from a byteArray, and yielded no result. I tried to convert it to a string, to see if it made any difference.
But it doesn't matter in the end, as I still get null from my property, weather it's a byteArray or string.

Comment: `UIImage` methods often returns `null` when the input data is invalid. To fix this you'll need to check the data at every step, e.g. is `originalImage.AsJPEG (0.23f)` returning something valid ? (save it to disk and open it in any image editing/previewing tool), and ensure it can roundtrip, e.g. does `UIImage.LoadFromData (originalImage.AsJPEG (0.23f));` return non null ?.

Comment: I want to thank you for your responses. The requirements of the projects have changed however, so I no longer have to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

NSData method not always a good solution. You can also try following

```
var rawData = pixelMap.ToByteArray();

        using (var provider = new CGDataProvider(rawData, 0, rawData.Length))
        {
            using (var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
            {
                var cgImage = new CGImage(
                    pixelMap.Width,
                    pixelMap.Height,
                    pixelMap.BitsPerComponent,
                    pixelMap.BytesPerPixel * ByteToBit,
                    pixelMap.BytesPerPixel * pixelMap.Width,
                    colorSpace,
                    CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrderDefault,
                    provider,
                    null,
                    true,
                    CGColorRenderingIntent.Default
                );

                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => UIImage.FromImage(cgImage).AsPNG().AsStream());
            }
        }
```

Check out my library and samples for more info about both Android and iOS bitmap from/to 2d pixel map. 
https://github.com/enginkirmaci/Imaging-Library